# Android SQLite database for quiz game

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making a quiz game and I would like to use SQLite database where I will store 300+ questions and randomly choose one of them. I made a research and I know how to create and update table, how to add, modify and delete rows within an Android app but I couldn't find a way to connect my app to an already done database (a read-only database stored in the resources(assets) folder).

Could you please help me?

Comment: Just an idea: Wouldn't it be better to parse a file (json/xml/whatever..) when app first starts into app's internal database? Does your asset file have to be a database file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should copy your DB file from assets folder to your installed application.
for example:

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private final static String DB_NAME = "YourDatabaseFile.sqlite";
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/%s/databases/";
private final String ERROR_TAG = "error";
private final static int DB_VERSION = 1;
private final int BUFFER_SIZE = 8 * 1024;
private SQLiteDatabase databaseHandle;

private final Context context;

public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

    this.context = context;
    DB_PATH = String.format(DB_PATH, context.getPackageName());
}

public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() {
    try {
        String databasePath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        if (databaseHandle == null) {
            createDataBase();
            databaseHandle = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(context.getResources().getString(R.string.err_opening_db), e);
    }
    return databaseHandle;
}

private boolean createDataBase() {
    try {
        if (!isDataBase()) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            copyDataBase();
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(context.getResources().getString(R.string.err_opening_db), e);
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        Log.e(ERROR_TAG, context.getResources().getString(R.string.err_close_stream), e);
    }

    return false;
}

public boolean isDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase verifiableDatabase = null;
    try {
        String databasePath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        verifiableDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        verifiableDatabase.close();
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e(ERROR_TAG, context.getResources().getString(R.string.err_opening_db), e);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream externalDbStream = null;
    OutputStream localDbStream = null;
    try {
        externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH+DB_NAME);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(context.getResources().getString(R.string.err_copying_db), e);
    }
    finally {
        if (localDbStream != null)
            localDbStream.close();
        if (externalDbStream != null)
            externalDbStream.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void close() {
    databaseHandle.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}}
```

Using:
`DatabaseOpenHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);

SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.openDataBase();`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complicated thing, ok not very complicated but You have to do some programming stuff. To read a database from asset folder is not directly possible, You have to copy it to the internal storage or to sd card. To explain it here is to much, please read this tutorial, that´s the right point to start:

http://zaman91.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/android-how-to-use-own-sqlite-database/