# Adding database to android application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I tried to search about adding a database to my android application but all solutions I found create a database at run time and start inserting and selecting from that database.

What I need is to add a database to my android application before run time because my database has data inside so I don't need to create an empty database once the application is run.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can add an existing db in your assets folder.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/

Comment: Iaalto is alway faster than me, when it comes to dbs... ;)

Comment: See my answer here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766312/android-sqlite-database-for-quiz-game/17767191#17767191

Comment: You can follow :

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application