# How to use my own sqlite database and search through it in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm a beginner in Android development. I'm trying to make an app where you search for name and show the matching results (from a database) in a listview. Since there's a lot of data, I thought it would be best to write a database without using the SQLiteOpenHandler. So now that I have my .db file, I need a way to be able to use it in my app from the assets folder and also to be able to search through it.

I found to links which I thought could be useful.

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

This shows how to use an existing database.

http://developer.android.com/training/search/search.html

And this is Google's information on storing and searching data. I need to know is it possible to somehow combine these two methods together to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: what kind of data are you trying to store in your database?

Comment: Text, such as name, age, birthdate, address etc. I want to search through these columns and return the matching data.

Comment: just follow the first link, do what they say, then use the database normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this extended SQLiteOpenHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766312/android-sqlite-database-for-quiz-game/17767191#17767191). It helps to copy the db file from `assets` folder in your application.